# Does it matter if I bring one or multiple fruits to Dr. Shrunk?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

When I bring a basket of fruits to Dr. Shrunk to teach me an emotion/animation, he makes a comment that he will have to teach me a "really good joke" that day compensate me for the many fruits that I brought.

I am curious to know if there is actually a game mechanic which restricts which emotions can be taught, or if that conversation is just a bit of fluff. Are there any emotions that cannot be taught by giving Dr. Shrunk a single fruit, or can they all be unlocked by bringing him a single fruit each day?

Comment: I have no idea how we'd actually verify an answer to this... How do you differentiate a "really good" emote from one that isn't? The joke book doesn't have different headings or anything for emotions.

Comment: @FAE I suppose the easiest way to verify would be through experience -- for example, is it possible to obtain every emotion by giving Dr. Shrunk a single fruit everyday?  I'll edit the question a bit, I think I can phrase that problem better.

Comment: He tells me the "really good joke" line even though I'm giving him cherries (my town fruit)...

Comment: I actually made a mistake and misclicked giving him 10,000 bells worth of turnips and he ate it just the same!

Answer (score 5):

Actually, there are no emotions that are unlocked by giving Dr. Shrunk multiple fruit in a day. You need to go to him each day with any fruit of your choice to receive a new emotion. I hope this helped!

Comment: and also, once you've learned all his "jokes," he just reruns his previous jokes. What a waste of a perfect peach *Facepalm*